# Passing hint to nhibernate using QueryExpressionPlan

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nhibernate

I am using NHibernate's QueryExpressionPlan to convert Hibernate Query Language to SQL.

Here's a sample code in C#:

```
var hql = SELECT _table0.Id FROM MyTable1 _table0 WHERE 1=1 and _table0.Address.ZipCode  LIKE   '%58745%' ;

var sql = NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryExpressionPlan
                 (new StringQueryExpression(hql), false, session.EnabledFilters, sessionFactory) ;
```

Here's the generated SQL. NHibernate is not able to add `INNER JOIN` to the generated SQL and returns records in comma separated format as shown below.

```
select myTable1.AssetId as col_0_0_ from MyTable1 myTable1, Address address1_ 
    where myTable1.AddressId=address1_.AddressID 
    and 1=1 and (address1_.ZipCode like '%58745%');
```

My query is what should I add to the QueryExpression so that it automatically adds inner join to the generated sql.

Or is it that NHibernate won't add the `INNER JOIN` by itself, and somehow i need to get that information myself and pass it to NHibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can define a `join` on NHibernate code using the `inner join` on the `HQL` statement. Take a look at the [`15.3. Associations and joins`](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/queryhql.html) on the documentation.

Remember that the `HQL` is `Hibernate Query Language` and it is based on your entity model (mapped classes) and not on your relation model (tables).

Remeber to bind the parameters on your hql statement and set it on the session. For sample:

```
var hql = "SELECT e.Id FROM MyEntity e 
           INNER JOIN e.Address a 
           WHERE a.ZipCode  LIKE :zipCode";

var zipCodeData = "58745";

var result = session.CreateQuery(hql)
                    .SetParameter("zipCode", $"%{zipCodeData}%")
                    .List<int>();
```